# PHP object exchange between servers

Tags: php, serialization

I got script what read from database and manipulate it so on the end I got $result array...
on one server

is it possible to serialize this object and pass it to other script so this $result array could be available for other script on second server...

I got on first server:

```
return serialize ( $results );
```

and on second:

```
$data = unserialize ( file_get_contents ( 'http://www.......com/reader.php' ) );
```

...but there is no communication between ....
What I am doing wrong ?

Bensiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. For arrays, you can simply use JSON, via `json_encode`. It is less error prone than `serialize`. However, you will have to output it (e.g.: `echo`), instead of returning it, for `file_get_contents` to be able to grab a result.

Instead of:

```
return serialize($results);
```

I'd suggest:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Then you could do:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.......com/reader.php'), true);
```

Comment: cool, however going thru json format I receive stdClass Object insted of array that is expected - I don't want to converting this - there is a big object and performance is very important

Comment: let me correct myself, I missed second parameter in json_decode (true) - this way I got array - that I need - THANK YOU